# SQL Server (Ubuntu): how to run Python script?

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, ubuntu

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 + SQL Server 2022. I have
installed Python 3.8
I an running python as an external script

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script  
@language =N'Python', 
@script=N' 
OutputDataSet = InputDataSet; 
', 
@input_data_1 =N'SELECT 1 AS hello' 
WITH RESULT SETS (([hello] int not null)); 
GO
```

but after timeout I see the message:

```
Msg 39012, Level 16, State 14, Line 29
Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'Python' script for request id: B59F3322-348C-4D7D-BF88-E20A5C965E7A. Please check the requirements of 'Python' runtime.
```

What I should check ?

Comment: Have you installed the required extensibility packages  for SQL Server, added the python libraries (as root), and configured the python runtimes?

Comment: I have installed extensibility etc. But I did not install revoscalepy . Do I need it?

Comment: You must follow *all* the instructions on [Install SQL Server 2022 ML Services on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-machine-learning-sql-2022?toc=%2Fsql%2Fmachine-learning%2Ftoc.json&view=sql-server-ver16).